# Send email to Jira from webform

Tags: jira

Are there any available methods to have a standard webform email an issue to JIRA, which would then create an issue?
We would need to include standard JIRA fields.
Your guidence will be much appriecated.

Answer (score 1):

Use a mailhandler for this type of task.

See https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira/creating-issues-and-comments-from-email-185729464.html